# How to subtract 2 SUM in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddp

I want to find the total outstanding amount for a particular item amount excluding the refund amount.

There will be two columns for each item based on number of times it was sold, `final_amount` and 2nd `refund_amount` for each items and I want to subtract total `refund_amount` from `final_amount` for each item.

PFB the code/query

```sql
SELECT item_id,
       SUM(final_amount) as total_amount,
       SUM(ISNULL(refund_amount, 0)) AS total_refund
       SUM(final_amount) - SUM(ISNULL(refund_amount, 0)) AS outstanding_amount                    
FROM tabel1 
WHERE item_id in ('119688521',
                  '109536343',
                  '99459466',
                  '97126817',
                  '138148320',
                  '107816131')
GROUP BY 1
```

I am getting a syntax error for "SUM" near

```
SUM(final_amount)-SUM(ISNULL(refund_amount, 0)) AS outstanding_amount
```

I tried different code:

```
SUM(total_amount - total_refund) AS npv
```

And I got the same error.

Comment: what's the `group by 1` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there's a few errors in syntax. You're missing a comma between all the select-elements (between your `total_refund` and `outstanding_amount`). You should also check if the `SUM()` was null, not if the column was null. You can also use `COALESCE()` if you prefer that. Finally, you need to `GROUP BY` something useful, like the `item_id`.

```
SELECT item_id,
       SUM(final_amount) as total_amount,
       ISNULL(SUM(refund_amount), 0) AS total_refund,
       SUM(final_amount) - ISNULL(SUM(refund_amount), 0) AS outstanding_amount
FROM tabel1 WHERE item_id in ('119688521',
                              '109536343',
                              '99459466',
                              '97126817',
                              '138148320',
                               '107816131')

GROUP BY item_id
```

- Live demo at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/94f518/5

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma.  In addition, you should check for `NULL` *after* the `SUM()`:

```
SELECT item_id,
       SUM(final_amount) as total_amount,
       COALESCE(SUM(refund_amount), 0) AS total_refund,
       (SUM(final_amount) - COALESCE(SUM(refund_amount), 0)
       )  AS outstanding_amount
FROM tabel1
WHERE item_id in ('119688521', '109536343', '99459466', '97126817', '138148320', '107816131')
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT item_id,
SUM(final_amount) as total_amount,
SUM(ISNULL(refund_amount, 0)) AS total_refund

SUM(final_amount - isnull(refund_amount, 0)) AS outstanding_amount

FROM tabel1 WHERE item_id in ('119688521',
'109536343',
'99459466',
'97126817',
'138148320',
'107816131')

GROUP BY item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing to put a comma (,) after your column ".... AS total_refund". Add the comma and this will resolve the syntax issue.

And please use GROUP BY item_id instead of GROUP BY 1